# Relative paths in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I'm trying to set the background of a dock panel in my WPF application.
Originally I had the full path hard coded in the image source attribute, but realise this is not best practice.

I set up an images folder in my project, and added the background image there. The directory looks like:

```
Solution:
 -Resources
  -Background.png
 -Project
  -bin
  -obj
  -properties
```

How can I set the background with this setup? At the moment I have this, which doesn't give me an error before running, but then throws an exception when I do.

```
<DockPanel.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource= "..\Resources\background.png"/>
</DockPanel.Background>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<DockPanel.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource= "Resources/background.png"/>
</DockPanel.Background>
```

Comment: And set the Build Action of the image file to Resource.

Comment: Nope, I get an xaml parse exception, how do i set the build action for the image?

Comment: The Resources folder has to be part of the Visual Studio project. The image's Build Action can be set in the Properties Window (Context Menu -> Properties).

Comment: There was my problem! My Resources folder wasn't in the project. Thank you. Sorry if that's simple, I literally started this today haha

Comment: @Stinkidog Good to know that your problem solved. Always Resource folder should be the part of project.